# More than 1 vanity urls for single landing page in pardot

Tags: landing-page, pardot

Is it feasible to have more than 1 vanity urls for single landing page in pardot?

Comment: Hi Ajay, welcome to SF.SE. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll also find the Search box on our site for previously answered questions. In your case, I believe you'll easily find the answer to your question by looking in the Salesforce Help or conducting a Google Search. This forum is more geared toward answering questions about the "how to's" of development than whether features exist.

Comment: @Ajay - remember to mark my answers as accepted if they were helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Custom Redirects](https://www.pardot.com/blog/custom-redirects/) - where you create multiple redirects to the same landing page. Each redirect can have its own vanity URL.